# A question about Galois group action on sheaves, descent theory and $\mu$-semistable sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $f : Y \to X$ be a finite morphism of degree $d$ of normal projective varieties over $k$ of dimension $n$. In Lehn and Huybrechts' book "[The Geometry of Moduli Space of Sheaves](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511711985)", there is a lemma:

Lemma 3.2.2: Let $F$ be an $n$-dimensional coherent sheaf on $X$. Then $F$ is $\mu$-semistable if and only if $f^{*}F$ is $\mu$-semistable. (Considered in Category $\operatorname{Coh}_{n,n-1}$.)

I can understand the 'if' part and reduce the 'only if' part to the case of $K(X) \subset K(Y)$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$. However, I failed to understand the following statement in the book：

“Suppose now that $f^{*}F$ is not $\mu$-semistable, and let $F'_{Y} \subset f^{*}F$ be the maximal destabilizing submodule. Because of its uniqueness, $F'_{Y}$ is invariant under the
action of $G$. By descent theory,there is a submodule $F' \subset F$ such that $f^{*}F'$ is isomorphic to  $F'_{Y}$. Thus $F'$ destabilizes $F$."

I guess that given an element $g \in G$,we can obtain an isomorphism $g$ of $Y$ such that
$f=fg$ and  $g \circ F'_{Y}=g^{*}F'_{Y}$. Then $f^{*}F$ is invariant under the action of $G$. By uniqueness,  $F'_{Y}$ is also invariant.

But, by an isomorphism of $K(Y)$, I can only get a birational map between $Y$, and I don't know how descent theory works. (In fact, I know almost nothing about descent theory.)
Can you give me some references?

Comment: The book you mention has two authors....... The Galois descent argument you want is covered in Friedman's book 'Algebraic surfaces and vector bundles', and in particular Theorem 28 on p272. The idea is that a Galois invariant subsheaf descends under such a morphism, and you can probably try to work this out first in the simpler case of a module.